# Tensorflow Estimator API: How to pass parameter from input function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to add class weights as a hyperparameter for my model, but to calculate weight I need to read input data, this happens inside input_fn which then passed to `estimator.fit()`. An output of `input_fn` are only features, labels which should have same shape num_examples * num_features. My questions - is there any way to propagate data from input_fn to model_fn's hyperparameter map? Or as alternative - maybe there is a wrapper for input_fn dataset which allows to oversample minority/undersample majority along with batching - in this case I would not need any parameter to propagate.

Comment: it may be important to specify if you use `tf.estimator.Estimator` or `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`. I believe there are slight differences between them

Comment: I'm using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator

Comment: Is the weight different for every batch? Can't you pass it as output along with features and labels?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn which I'm using require all outputs to be equal is size, I probably can reshape weights to make it the same size as features. But I was wondering if there is cleaner way of passing parameters generated by dataset, which are not features and labels.

Answer (score 1):

Both features and labels can be dictionary of tensors (not just one tensor). The tensors can be any shape you want though it's common to be num_examples * ...

If you don't use any of the predefined estimators, the easiest way would be to add another feature with what you need to compute the weights, compute the weights in the model then use them (multiply the loss or pass it as a parameter).

You also have access to hyper parameters inside the input_fn so you can compute the weight there and add it as a separate column.

If you use a canned estimator check the documentation. I see most of them   support a weight_column_name. In this case just give it the name you used in the features dictionary for the weight values.

Alternatively, if all else fails you can sample the data the way you want before you feed it to tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think that functions provided by TF allow tensors in feature dict to be any shape - (e.g. [numpy_input_fn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/numpy_io.py#L143)), I always can write my own function or write my own sampling logic. But I was wondering if there any preferred way of doing this. Because looks like there are no support at all for imbalanced classes provided by Estimator API natively. I was intended to use separate feature column of the dataset size, duplicating weights for each record.

Comment: Unbalanced classes are hard to handle generically. If the imbalance is slight you can use example weights. If the imbalance is larger weights will create a lot of noise in your gradients so it might work better if you replicate examples so that the average weight of a batch is more or less the same across batches. If the imbalance is larger still you might have to oversample the small class or undersample the large one. As always you need to try them out and see what works for your problem.