# Question about `input_fn` in Tensorflow's multi worker estimator tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_estimator), function `input_fn` has a param named `mode`. I can't figure out how this param get passed to `input_fn` when training.

```py
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64

def input_fn(mode, input_context=None):
  datasets, info = tfds.load(name='mnist',
                                with_info=True,
                                as_supervised=True)
  mnist_dataset = (datasets['train'] if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN else
                   datasets['test'])

  def scale(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /= 255
    return image, label

  if input_context:
    mnist_dataset = mnist_dataset.shard(input_context.num_input_pipelines,
                                        input_context.input_pipeline_id)
  return mnist_dataset.map(scale).cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

To better clarify my question, see how this input_fn is passed as a function param. It is just passed without any wrapper that give `mode` a value.

```py
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
    classifier,
    train_spec=tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=input_fn),
    eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=input_fn)
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow Estimator API: How to pass parameter from input function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372837/tensorflow-estimator-api-how-to-pass-parameter-from-input-function)

Comment: @M.Innat Thanks for your reply. I've read this question, but the answer doesn't seem to be the right one.